# i am trying to install pyboost for rdkit but it showing following problems

Tags: rdkit

pin-1 is installable and it requires
│  └─ python 3.12.* , which can be installed;
├─ py-boost is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ py-boost 1.82.0, which can be installed;
│  ├─ py-boost [1.65.1|1.67.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ py-boost [1.65.1|1.67.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.5,<3.6.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ py-boost [1.65.1|1.67.0|1.71.0|1.73.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ py-boost [1.67.0|1.71.0|1.73.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ py-boost 1.71.0 would require
│  │  └─ libboost >=1.71.0,<1.71.1.0a0 haf77d95_0, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
│  ├─ py-boost [1.71.0|1.73.0|1.82.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ py-boost [1.71.0|1.73.0|1.82.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  ├─ py-boost [1.71.0|1.73.0|1.82.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│  └─ py-boost 1.82.0 would require
│     └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
└─ rdkit is not installable because there are no viable options
├─ rdkit [2023.03.3|2023.09.1|...|2023.09.5] would require
│  └─ libboost-python >=1.82.0,<1.83.0a0  but there are no viable options
│     ├─ libboost-python 1.82.0 would require
│     │  └─ py-boost <0.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│     ├─ libboost-python 1.82.0 would require
│     │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│     ├─ libboost-python 1.82.0 would require
│     │  └─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│     ├─ libboost-python 1.82.0 would require
│     │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
│     └─ libboost-python 1.82.0 would require
│        └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2017.09.3|2018.03.1|...|Release_2017_09_3] would require
│  └─ python [2.7* |>=2.7,<2.8.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2017.09.3|2018.03.1|...|Release_2017_09_3] would require
│  └─ python [3.5* |>=3.5,<3.6.0a0 ], which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2017.09.3|Release_2017_09|Release_2017_09_3] would require
│  └─ python 3.6* , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2018.03.1|2018.03.2|...|2021.03.5] would require
│  └─ python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2018.03.4|2018.09.1|...|2022.09.1] would require
│  └─ python >=3.7,<3.8.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2019.09.1|2019.09.2|...|2023.09.5] would require
│  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2020.03.6|2020.09.1|...|2023.09.5] would require
│  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
├─ rdkit [2022.03.1|2022.03.2|...|2023.09.5] would require
│  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
└─ rdkit [2022.09.1|2022.09.3|...|2023.09.5] would require
└─ python >=3.11,<3.12.0a0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

any solutions or tutorial to install rdkit